# What is the moral of Zootopia?

Tags: analysis, zootopia

Watching the movie, I was wondering what the moral of Zootopia is supposed be.

The story has the "dumb bunny" given the opportunity to stay low, to stay safe in the farm with her parents, but instead she chooses to risk everything and follow her dream!

So I think the moral is *"Are you gonna settle or are you going  try everything?"*

Did I get it right? If not, what is it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the moral of the story is **"Don't judge book by its cover"**. The whole movie is against stereotypes.

The bunny should be a carrot farmer, because that's what bunnies do,
the predators are bullies an deep down everyone feels that way, because when assumption is made that only predators are going feral, everyone accepts it as truth.

You can see that even the fox is bullied for being a predator because he is perceived as one.

Comment: I thought of that too Zikato, yes! However my post was frozen, so I couldn't edit. So, I would conclude, like the aftermath of Aesop's Fable, that the moral of this nice movie is a combinations of what I am saying and you said. PS - Credits to cde for taking the time (and mostly for having the sharpness needed) to revive that question!